# Uninstalling snapd broke networking on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: networking, snap

While working on a different problem I decided to uninstall snapd on one of my Ubuntu Server 22.04 boxes because I wasn't using it. Now that it is removed the server refuses all network connections. I can see that it has the correct ip (I use OPNSense to pin it to a specific one). I can't ssh to it, nginx refuses all connections, and the webmin interface also won't work. Not sure what to do here, and was hoping for some guidance eon troubleshooting.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to reinstall `snapd` and then run `snap list` to see all the snap apps that are installed.  If you can't install `snapd` then you are looking at a reinstallation of the server.

Comment: It looks like uninstalling snapd took resolveconf with it... :(

Comment: This smells like yet another instance of a human not reading their apt output before agreeing to package uninstalls. Debian users also need to read their apt output.

Comment: Removing snapd *shouldn't* remove other critical components like the dns resolver. What's the output from `/var/log/dpkg.log` from the point in time when you removed snapd? Maybe put that in a pastebin like paste.debian.net.

Comment: Yeah, Debian won fix a PEBKAC but it has less stuff on it that would feel compelled to uninstall.

@popey I made things worse trying to fix it and lost the output. I backed up the important things and and going to learn from my mistake. Thanks everyone!